# how to update without duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table

| Id | Name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 15 |
| 2 | a | 14 |
| 3 | c | 14 |
| 4 | c | 15 |
| 5 | d | 15 |
| 6 | f | 14 |
| 7 | g | 15 |

I want to update where type = 15 to 14 for all.
but there are some already with the type 14 of same name
how can I update only the distinct

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid updated rows that would produce duplicates, you can use `not exists` in the `update`:

```
update t
    set type = 14
    where type = 15 and
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.name = t.name and t2.type = 14
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable p1 SET p1.type= '14' WHERE p1.type IN 
    (SELECT p2.id from mytable p2 WHERE p2.type = '15');
```